# Design a Search Friendly (i.e. Crawlable) Widget

Tags: php, iframe, widget, google-crawlers

I offer a widget to my clients which when deployed on their webpage display pricing data. The widget is written in PHP and is deployed using an iframe as follows

```
<iframe  id="widget" src="http://www.example.com/customers/widget.php"
style="width:290px;height:210px; border:none;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Inside the widget, I have an anchor tag which links back to my website

```
Powered by <a href="http://www.example.com">example.com</a>
```

and I want this to be crawled by Googlebot etc so I could get an SERPS link from it.

A couple of my clients have deployed the widget but it doesn't look like the iframe content is crawled by Google. Essentially I'm not seeing a link back from these websites. The webpages where the widget is deployed are well ranked in google (PR 2,3) and have good domain authority - so I know thats not the issue.

Is there a better way to deploy the widget (instead of iframe) to make it crawlable by google?

Comment: See http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12384/how-good-is-it-for-seo-if-you-have-a-widget-that-lives-on-other-sites/12385#12385

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about what sort of content is favoured by Google. Try http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @JohnConde. I will check out your link. Sorry if I posted this in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google will not count links inside iframes because your client's website is basically loading the content from *your* website (so it's counted as a link from *your own* website instead from that of your client). Ususally, the widget creator would provide a copy & paste ready snippet that an interested webmaster would take and insert in his website like this:

```
<iframe  id="widget" src="http://www.example.com/customers/widget.php"
style="width:290px;height:210px; border:none;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
<p>Powered by <a href="http://www.example.com">example.com</a></p>
```

In your case, you would simply place the link to your page below the iframe, not in it.

### One word of caution

That being said, I would **strongly** advise you to add a `rel=nofollow` to the "Powered by ..." link. Otherwise you're running the risk of getting your page penalized. From the [Google guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356?hl=en):

> Additionally, creating links that weren’t editorially placed or
>   vouched for by the site’s owner on a page, otherwise known as
>   unnatural links, can be considered a violation of our guidelines. Here
>   are a few common examples of unnatural links that may violate our
>   guidelines:
>
> [...]
>
> Keyword-rich, hidden or low-quality links embedded in widgets that are
>   distributed across various sites, for example ...

Altough you're not using a "keyword rich anchor" in your example we have seen cases where widget links like these have been reported as problematic in the Google Webmaster Tools.

Comment: Thanks Hirnhamster. Ultimately I think I need a solution as suggested by @JohnConde but your post answer the question I posed here.. Thanks for the tip on the no-follow as well.